# Creating a bar graph in R with a numerical predictor and binary outcome

Tags: r, graph

I am trying to make a bar graph with height(continuous and numerical) as a response to outcome of heart disease(binary yes/no). My dataset named data2 has 540 observations and the variable names I am looking at are height vs heartdisease. I am trying to categorize the height into 5cm cut off groups.

```
library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data.frame(
  height = runif(n = 540, min = 0, max = 140),
  heartdisease = sample(x = c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 1000, replace = TRUE)
)

breaks <- c(145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175)

# Create height groups using the cut() function
data2$height_group <- cut(data2$height, 
                          breaks = breaks, 
                          labels = c("<145", "145-150", "150-155", "155-160",
                                     "160-165", "165-170", "170-175"))

# Create a bar graph
ggplot(data2, aes(x = height_group, fill = factor(heartdisease))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = "Height Categories (per 5 cm)", 
       y = "Count", 
       title = "Height in centimeters vs heart disease") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("No", "Yes")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

I tried using the code above, but it said issue in first layer and produced no output.

Comment: `Error in cut.default(data2$height, breaks = breaks, labels = c("145-150",  : 
  lengths of 'breaks' and 'labels' differ`. Check your code: there are 7 breaks and 5 labels.

Comment: even with this change the plot will not produce

Comment: When I fix the mistakes in the example you prepared (`data2` is attempting to create columns of different lengths, and as noted you need another value in `breaks`, probably a 0 at the beginning) your ggplot code runs without error or warning and generates a plot. However, if only produces one bar, because you generated data in only one of your height groups.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issues are being caused by unsuitable example data; if you change your example input ("data2") your code works as expected;

```r
library(tidyverse)

data2 <- data.frame(
  height = runif(n = 540, min = 140, max = 180),
  heartdisease = sample(x = c(TRUE, FALSE), size = 540, replace = TRUE)
)

# Create height groups using the cut() function
data2$height_group <- cut(data2$height, 
                                 breaks = c(-Inf, 145, 150, 155, 160, 165, 170, 175, Inf), 
                                 labels = c("<145", "145-150", "150-155", "155-160",
                                     "160-165", "165-170", "170-175", "175+"))

# Create a bar graph
ggplot(data2, aes(x = height_group, fill = factor(heartdisease))) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(x = "Height Categories (per 5 cm)", 
       y = "Count", 
       title = "Height in centimeters vs heart disease") +
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("No", "Yes")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-02 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>